# How to print a matrix so that there are distinct rows and columns?

Tags: python

I want to print a 2D LIST - the desired outcome would be printing 3 rows each containing 4 elements, but the output is a continuous line.

```
empty = []
row = []
for i in range(0,3):
   empty.append("\n")#Is this not allowed in python?
for j in range(0,4):
   var1 = int(input("please enter an integer value for row " + str(i+1) + " column " + str(j+1)))

   row.append(var1)
   empty.append(row)
   row= []  

print(empty)
```

Comment: You can create a numpy array out of it

Comment: `empty` starts out empty and you add 3 new lines. Then you add the rows, but you never add a new line in between the rows. Have you formatted your code in this example exactly how you have it in your editor?

Comment: I assume the second for loop is meant to be nested within the first? Even after doing that, you are adding a series of strings `"\n"` and ints to the array `empty`. Printing an array will always just give you a "continuous list". If you want to control the formatting you need to create a string formatted the way you want it.

Comment: Hey.  Did this help you out?  I'm just going back and checking answers I posted to see if I can help more or if I can figure out why my answer wasn't accepted or upvoted by the person who asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy to create an array

```
import numpy
print(np.array(empty))
```

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on @NikitParakh's idea, here's how you would get the specific result you asked for using `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

empty = np.zeros((3, 4))
for i in range(0, 3):
    for j in range(0, 4):
        empty[i][j] = int(input("please enter an integer value for row " + str(i+1) + " column " + str(j+1) + " >"))

print(empty)
```

Running this code gives you something like this:

```
please enter an integer value for row 1 column 1 >11
please enter an integer value for row 1 column 2 >22
...
please enter an integer value for row 3 column 4 >1212
[[  11.   22.   33.   44.]
 [  55.   66.   77.   88.]
 [  99. 1010. 1111. 1212.]]
```

you can also do this using nested Python `list`s:

```
empty = []
for i in range(0, 3):
    empty.append([])
    for j in range(0, 4):
        var1 = int(input("please enter an integer value for row " + str(i+1) + " column " + str(j+1) + " >"))
        empty[i].append(var1)
for i in range(len(empty)):
    print(empty[i])
```

Result:

```
please enter an integer value for row 1 column 1 >1
please enter an integer value for row 1 column 2 >2
...
please enter an integer value for row 3 column 4 >12
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
[9, 10, 11, 12]
```

You could put more work into the printing of the matrix to make it nicer...more like what Pandas does.  Saving that work, and the many other benefits Pandas can offer, is why you use it.